# How to implement sticky posts in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

wordpress support stick post function. and store the stick info in `wp_options` table named `sticky_posts` and will autoload.

so I dig into the sql created by wp, (add `log = /tmp/mysql.log` in my.cnf). open the index page of wordpress. sticky posts shows normally. but when I look at sql, found all wp_posts related sql, there is no stick ids used. so how wp implemented the stick ?

all wp_posts related queries:

```
      130 Query SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 3


      130 Query SELECT * FROM wp_posts  WHERE (post_type = 'page' AND post_status = 'publish')     ORDER BY menu_order, post_title ASC


      130 Query SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5


      130 Query SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS `year`, MONTH(post_date) AS `month`, count(ID) as posts FROM wp_posts  WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY YEAR(post_date), MONTH(post_date) ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

Comment: i got the answer. wordpress will first check if stick posts are in the result. if yes: nothing happened. if no, execute another query to fetch sticky posts. that's it.

Answer (score -1):

[image: How to sticky a post in Wordpress]